# Is their any example of how to use Winapi.Security.Cryptography.pas in delphi?

Tags: delphi, winapi

I found in the Delphi source code the unit `Winapi.Security.Cryptography`, but I didn't find any example of how to use it. Particularly I would like to do an **RSA Signature with SHA-256** from this unit, but I don't know form where to start.

For example given this declaration:

```
  {
  // Used Types:  Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.IAsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider
  // Used Types:  String
  }
  // Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.IAsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProviderStatics
  [WinRTClassNameAttribute(SCore_AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider)]
  Core_IAsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProviderStatics = interface(IInspectable)
  ['{425BDE18-A7F3-47A6-A8D2-C48D6033A65C}']
    function OpenAlgorithm(algorithm: HSTRING): Core_IAsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider; safecall;
  end;
```

How to use it in Delphi ?

Comment: I would start at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.cryptography.core?view=winrt-18362 There are some examples there how to do specific tasks in C# but they don't seem to hard to translate. look for classes implementing interfaces in Winapi.Security.Cryptography They have class properties and functions for accessing that functionality.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar thanks: I don't even know, does we need something special to use WinRT ? those libraries seam to be connected to winRT

Comment: You don't need anything special. That WinRT refers to API name, not Windows RT version (that is AFAIK dead duck). But you need Windows 10 to run those APIs. For instance you can call `TCore_AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(TCore_AsymmetricAlgorithmNames.EcdsaSha256)` and it will return you provider interface for specific algorithm...

Comment: Data is first hashed, and [`CryptSignHash`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptsignhasha) is used to sign the hash. You can refer to [Example C Program: Signing a Hash and Verifying the Hash Signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/example-c-program-signing-a-hash-and-verifying-the-hash-signature).

Comment: And it is suggested to use [`NCryptSignHash`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ncrypt/nf-ncrypt-ncryptsignhash) instead of CryptSignHash because this API is deprecated.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar you mean I can not use them under windows 8.1 ?

Comment: The Windows Runtime was introduced in Windows 8, but this particular API is available on Windows 10 only.